# json пропуск value если нет данных

Tags: python, json

```
files_stor = '[{'name': 'Основные характеристики'}, {'name': 'Тип сканера', 'value': 'Высокоскоростной лазерный 3D-сканер с комбинированный сервоприводом'}, {'name': 'Интерфейс', 'value': 'Внешнее управление'}, {'name': 'Управление', 'value': 'Полевой контроллер'}, {'name': 'cI', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'Камера', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'Возможности 3D-сканирования'}, {'name': 'Применение', 'value': 'Наземный 3D-сканер'}, {'name': 'Скорость сканирования', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'Класс лазера', 'value': '1 класс'}, {'name': 'Максимальная дальность', 'unit': 'cJ', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'Минимальная дальность', 'unit': 'cJ', 'value': '0.6'}, {'name': 'Поле зрения  ', 'value': '360°/282°'}, {'name': 'Точность 3D-модели', 'value': '3,5 мм на 20 м'}, {'name': 'Угловая точность', 'unit': '"', 'value': '21'}, {'name': 'Точность дальномера', 'value': '2 мм'}, {'name': 'Уровень шума', 'value': '3 мм на 60 м'}, {'name': 'Возможности визуализации'}, {'name': 'Встроенная камера', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'Камеры', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'Внешняя камера', 'value': 'cK'}, {'name': 'HDR', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'IR камера', 'value': 'cK'}, {'name': 'Скорость съемки', 'value': '1 мин'}, {'name': 'Производительность системы'}, {'name': 'Тип компенсатора', 'value': 'Двухосевой компенсатор'}, {'name': 'Разрешение ', 'value': '1"'}, {'name': 'Диапазон работы компенсатора', 'value': "± 5'"}, {'name': 'Точность установки компенсатора', 'value': '± 3"'}, {'name': 'Управление и запись данных '}, {'name': 'Выбор области сканирования', 'value': 'По видеоизображению'}, {'name': 'cI', 'value': 'invalid_key'}, {'name': 'Передача данных', 'value': 'WLAN, USB'}, {'name': 'Дисплей', 'value': 'cK'}, {'name': 'Питание'}, {'name': 'Тип', 'value': 'Съемный аккумулятор'}, {'name': 'Тип батареи', 'value': 'Li-Ion'}, {'name': 'Время работы', 'value': '4 ч'}, {'name': 'Окружающая среда'}, {'name': 'Рабочая температура', 'value': 'от –20°C'}, {'name': 'Температура хранения', 'value': 'от –40°C до + 70°C'}, {'name': 'Защищенность', 'value': 'IP55'}, {'name': 'Размеры и вес сканера'}, {'name': 'Размеры сканера', 'unit': 'мм', 'value': '178 x 353 x 170'}, {'name': 'Вес сканера без аккумулятора', 'unit': 'invalid_key', 'value': '5.8'}, {'name': 'Вес аккумулятора', 'unit': 'invalid_key', 'value': '0.35'}]'

files_info = json.loads(files_stor)
print(files_info)
try:
    for file_info in files_info:
        print(f"{file_info['value']}")
except KeyError as ke:
        print('none')
```

на выходе у меня все none
как сделать где нет ключа value писать none, а где есть писать название ключа value?

Comment: Но вы же всегда можете проверить есть ли ключ в словаре: `if 'value' in file_info:` и дальше делать что вам нужно. А так то просто нужно было `try/except` делать **внутри цикла**, а не снаружи.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо тупанул чет я

Answer (score 0):

```
for file_info in files_info:
    try:
        print(f"{file_info['value']}")
    except KeyError as ke:
        print('none')
```